# store transaction Id  into magento order payment table

Tags: magento

I have created my own payment method by taking reference of another method. I wannt to store my payment gateway's transaction id to order payment details  (sales/order_payment) on successful payment action.

How can I store transaction id to this table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add an SQL install script to your module, where we will add a new attribute to the order object

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'Transaction Code',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,  
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'new_transaction_id', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

you could then add a observer to hook the payment event, so you would need to add code to yoru config.xml to enable your observer to hook onto the event:

```
<events>
   <sales_order_payment_pay>
      <observers>
        <my_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>mymodule/observer</class>
            <method>save_transaction</method>
        </my_observer>
      </observers>
   </sales_order_payment_pay>     
</events>
```

You would then add an observer model to your module:

```
<?php
class Company_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function save_transaction($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getInvoice()->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order

        /**
         * You would need to have your tranaction id from your gateway
         * which would depend on how you have made your module..
         * ....
         */
        try {
            $order->setNewTransactionId($transactionId);
            $order->save();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            // do something nice
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the above answer works I think there may be a better way to store the information.

Add the following method to your payment modules model.

```
public function assignData($data)
{
    if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $data = new Varien_Object($data);
    }

    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

    $info->setYourCustomTransactionId($data->getYourCustomTransactionId());

    return $this;
}
```

While this would work. I would suggest using adding another method to your payment module. setAdditionalInformation and set the data via the assignData method. I'm not sure this method is already there if your payment method is derived from another magento payment class.

```
public function setAdditionalInformation($key, $value)
{
    if (is_object($value)) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Payment transactions disallow storing objects.'));
    }
    $info = $this->_getData('additional_information');
    if (!$info) {
        $info = array();
    }
    $info[$key] = $value;
    return $this->setData('additional_information', $info);
}
```

Then you would do this in assign data.

```
public function assignData($data)
{
    if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $data = new Varien_Object($data);
    }

    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

    $info->setAdditionalInformation(array(
        'trans_id' => $data->getYourCustomTransactionId()
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

This may not work for your implementation, but I think it might be a little cleaner way of storing the info.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've sorted this Issue doing the following:

Change the function `capture()` at `app/code/local/SecurePay/Sxml/Model/Sxml.php` to something like that:

```
    if($approved)
    {
        $transaction_id = $sxml->getResult('transaction_id');
        
        $xmlResponse = $sxml->getResult('response');
        $response = simplexml_load_string(htmlspecialchars_decode($xmlResponse))->children();
        
        $payment->setAdditionalInformation('txnID', (string) $response->Payment->TxnList->Txn->txnID);
        $payment->setAdditionalInformation('purchaseOrderNo', (string) $response->Payment->TxnList->Txn->purchaseOrderNo);          
        $payment->setCcTransId(''.$transaction_id);
```

That is all.